# Wordpress - How to add password length to password-strength-meter.js

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I would like to add the option to detect the minimum length of characters in the input password attached to password-strength-meter.js.To show the message in the same div when the password is too short. Is this even possible? Something like this:

```
wp_localize_script( 'password-strength-meter', 'pwsL10n', array(
'empty' => __( 'Strength indicator' ),
'tooshort' => __( 'Password require min 7 chars' ),
'short' => __( 'Very weak' ),
'bad' => __( 'Weak' ),
'good' => _x( 'Medium', 'password strength' ),
'strong' => __( 'Strong' ),
'mismatch' => __( 'Mismatch' )
));
```

Comment: Does the plugin have documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function provided by the password-strength-meter.js script:

```
wp.passwordStrength.meter( password1, blacklist, password2);
```

But you will have to create you own js function to do your check.
Don't forget to modify pwsL10n in order to add "tooshort" and to be able to localiz it.

Take a look a this tuto: 
https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/using-the-included-password-strength-meter-script-in-wordpress--wp-34736

Comment: ya, i;m already using this. But how to modify pwsL10n? Where i should add "tooshort"? By addind new case?  case 6:
    $('#pass-strength-result').addClass('tooshort').html( pwsL10n.tooshort );

Comment: Yes you will have to add a case because you need to manage "tooshort" but before (after the enqueue i guess) you will have to modify the pwsL10n object. Try first a console.log to check the structure then try to add the new value (i must be an object) that you will name "tooshort".

Maybe something like this will work, you have to try:

pwsL10n.push(new_object);